# Best RGB combination to convert image into Black and White "threshold"

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am required to build a simple application that converts a color image or a grayscale image into a black and white one, I was thinking looping through each pixel and checking the RGB values and if all of them are less than an specific value (lets say 20) redraw the pixel to black and if it is greater than that value, redraw the pixel to white. Something like this.

```
function blackWhite(context, canvas) {
    var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var pixels  = imgData.data;
        for (var i = 0, n = pixels.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        if (pixels[i] <= 20 || pixels[i+1] <= 20 || pixels[i+2] <= 20){ 
              pixels[i  ] = 0;        // red
           pixels[i+1] = 0;        // green
           pixels[i+2] = 0;        // blue
        }else{
              pixels[i  ] = 255;        // red
           pixels[i+1] = 255;        // green
           pixels[i+2] = 255;        // blue
        }
    }
    //redraw the image in black & white
    context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
  }
```

The big question is, what is the correct combination of Red, green and blue to define a pixel to be black, this taking into account that colors are perceived different by the human eye, as an example for our eyes it is more important the green color than the red and the blue, I’ve tried experimentally some values, but I don’t get close to a black and with image like the one you could get by digitalizing a sheet in an scanner as black and white.

Of course if there is a much faster way to do this, I will totally appreciate it.

Comment: You just want on and off, not grayscale. Correct?

Comment: Naively, I'd say 128, but a more elaborate answer would do preliminary analysis on the individual image's histogram to determine what the appropriate threshold would be.

Comment: Yes, actually grayscale is different than black and white in that sense

Comment: Are you talking about a threshold?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)

Comment: Yes, totally, I didn't know that term, Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the relative luminance. While not the most advanced method of thresholding, it better follows the way humans perceive light, which is what I think you want.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance

From the wikipedia article the luminance can be calculated as follows:

`let lum = .2126 * red + .7152 * green + .0722 * blue`

This value will be some fraction of one so if you want to split it right in the middle use a threshold of .5

**EDIT**

The real issue comes with selecting the threshold. Not all images are lit the same way and a picture with more pixels with a low luminosity (i.e., more blacks) will benefit from a lower threshold. 
There's a couple techniques you can consider using such as analyzing the histogram of the image.

Comment: Thanks man, This is really helpful, If you know how to do the analyzing of the histogram, it would be pretty great, but by far this is pretty enough.

Comment: Creating a histogram like this isn't actually that difficult. Check out this tutorial on how to create a histogram. https://billmill.org/the_histogram.html 
Once you have your histogram array, you can analyze it using a Balanced Histogram Thresholding algorithm. That algorithm will return a threshold for you to use in your analysis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_histogram_thresholding

Comment: Also should mention that you should keep in check what range of values you're getting. Stay consistent if you're using values between 0 and 1 for your thresholding algorithm and etc. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry but you have the calculation incorrect. Using channels R,G,B the correct Lum values for the relative luminance `lum =  Math.sqrt(R * R * 0.2126 + G * G * 0.7152 + B * B * 0.0722)` Though this still does not get you the correct value and does not account for media type (eg monitor type, print format, environmental)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. You're right that the calculation isn't correct as I failed to mention the conversion from sRGB to linear RGB. Do you have a source or explanation for this formula?

Comment: @Blindman67 que?? That looks like a game-coder's formula :) However, it won't produce the correct result. To linearize color data you would use the inverse gamma with normalized RGB (or gray) values, ie. you need know the gamma used in the first place (usually stored in the file as a fixed value, or in an embedded ICC profile) - there is no general approach unless approximation is acceptable (which is anyways what one does with non-linear data). My 2 cents.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm adding this for future visitors.) For converting images to black & white where the characteristics such as luma dominance, gamma etc. are unknown, the "[Otsu's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method)" tends to provide good results.

It's a fairly simple algorithm which uses a luma histogram of the image combined with pixel count to find an optimal cluster-based threshold value.

The main steps are (source: ibid):

[image: steps]

### Building a Histogram

So the first thing we need to do is to build a histogram. This will require converting RGB to luminance using either a flat 33.3% factor or as in Khauri's answer a Rec.709 (for HD) formula (Rec. 601 can be used as well). Note that Rec.* factors assumes that the RGB is converted to linear format; modern browsers will typically apply gamma (non-linear) to the image used for canvas. But lets ignore that here.

A flat conversion can be beneficial performance wise but provides less accurate result:

```
var luma = Math.round((r + g + b) * 0.3333);
```

while Rec.709 will give a better result (with linear data):

```
var luma = Math.round(r * 0.2126 + g * 0.7152 + b * 0.0722);
```

So, convert each pixel to integer luma value, use the resulting value as index in a 256 large array and increment for the index:

```js
var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
var histogram = new Uint16Array(256); // assuming smaller images here, ow: Uint32

// build the histogram using Rec. 709 for luma
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var luma = Math.round(data[i++] * 0.2126 + data[i++] * 0.7152 + data[i++] * 0.0722);
  histogram[luma]++;   // increment for this luma value
}
```

### Find Optimal Cluster-based Threshold value

Now that we have a histogram we can feed that to the Oto's method and obtain a black & white version of the image.

Translated into JavaScript we would do (source for method part based on [variant 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method#Variant_2) from ibid):

```js
// Otsu's method, from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method#Variant_2
//
// The input argument pixelsNumber is the number of pixels in the given image. The 
// input argument histogram is a 256-element histogram of a grayscale image 
// different gray-levels.
// This function outputs the threshold for the image.
function otsu(histogram, pixelsNumber) {
  var sum = 0, sumB = 0, wB = 0, wF = 0, mB, mF, max = 0, between, threshold = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    wB += histogram[i];
    if (wB === 0) continue;
    wF = pixelsNumber - wB;
    if (wF === 0) break;
    sumB += i * histogram[i];
    mB = sumB / wB;
    mF = (sum - sumB) / wF;
    between = wB * wF * Math.pow(mB - mF, 2);
    if (between > max) {
      max = between;
      threshold = i;
    }
  }
  return threshold>>1;
}

// Build luma histogram
var c = document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "";
img.onload = go;
img.src = "//i.imgur.com/tbRxrWA.jpg";

function go() {
  c.width = this.width;
  c.height = this.height;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  var idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  var data = idata.data;
  var histogram = new Uint16Array(256);
  
  // build the histogram using flat factors for RGB
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    // note: here we also store luma to red-channel for reuse later.
    var luma = data[i] = Math.round(data[i]*.2126+data[i+1]*.7152+data[i+2]*.0722);
    histogram[luma]++;
  }
  
  // Get threshold
  var threshold = otsu(histogram, c.width * c.height);
  console.log("Threshold:", threshold);
  
  // convert image
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    // remember we stored luma to red channel.. or use a separate array for luma values
    data[i] = data[i+1] = data[i+2] = data[i] >= threshold ? 255 : 0;
  }
  
  // show result
  ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
  document.body.appendChild(c);     // b&w version
  document.body.appendChild(this);  // original image below
}
```

Also see the [improvements section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method#Improvements).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

I did not read the question correctly so I have updated the answer to reflect the question. Will leave old answer in just as a point of interest for those that are.

To create the simplest threshold filter just sum the RGB channels and if over the threshold value the make pixel white else black.

```
// assumes canvas and ctx defined;
// image to process, threshold level range 0 - 255
function twoTone(image, threshold) {
  ctx.drawImage(image,0,0):
  const imgD = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const d = imgD.data;
  var v,i = 0;
  while (i < d.length) {
    v = (d[i++] + d[i++] + d[i]) < (threshold * 3) ? 0 : 255;
    i -= 2;
    d[i++] = d[i++] = d[i++] = v;
    i++;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgD, 0, 0);
}
```

But there are other ways. A modification of the above lets you create a gradient at the threshold. This softens the hard boundary that the above method can produce.

Sometimes you need the function to be quick, or you may not be able to access the pixel data due to cross origin security restrictions. In that case you can use a stack composite operation approch that creates a threshold by layering the image in a succession of "multiply" and "lighter" `globalCompositeOperations`. Though this method can produce high quality results, the input values are a little fuzzy as presented in the example below. You would have to calibrate it if you wanted to match the specific threshold and cutoff width.

#### Demo

#### UPDATE

As there is more information in the form of answers i have updated the code to keep the comparisons fair.

I have updated the demo to include **K3N** image of the bear and have provided 3 methods for finding the threshold via a mean. (I have modified the code in K3N's answer to fit the demo. It is functionally the same). The Buttons at the top let you select from the two images and display size and the last three find and apply the threshold value using three methods.

Use the sliders to change the threshold and cutoff and amount values where applicable.

```js
const image = new Image;
const imageSrcs = ["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png", "//i.imgur.com/tbRxrWA.jpg"];
var scaleFull = false;
var imageBWA;
var imageBWB;
var imageBWC;
var amountA = -1;
var thresholdA = -1;
var thresholdB = -1;
var cutoffC = -1;
var thresholdC = -1;


start();
//Using stacked global composite operations.
function twoTone(bw, amount, threshold) {
  bw.ctx.save();
  bw.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation";
  bw.ctx.fillStyle = "#888"; // no saturation
  bw.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, bw.width, bw.height);
  amount /= 16;
  threshold = 255 - threshold;

  while (amount-- > 0) {
    bw.ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    bw.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    bw.ctx.drawImage(bw, 0, 0);
    const a = (threshold / 127);
    bw.ctx.globalAlpha = a > 1 ? 1 : a;
    bw.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
    bw.ctx.drawImage(bw, 0, 0);
    if (a > 1) {
      bw.ctx.globalAlpha = a - 1 > 1 ? 1 : a - 1;
      bw.ctx.drawImage(bw, 0, 0);
      bw.ctx.drawImage(bw, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  bw.ctx.restore();
}

// Using per pixel processing simple threshold.
function twoTonePixelP(bw, threshold) {
  const imgD = bw.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, bw.width, bw.height);
  const d = imgD.data;
  var i = 0;
  var v;
  while (i < d.length) {
    v = (d[i++] + d[i++] + d[i]) < (threshold * 3) ? 0 : 255;
    i -= 2;
    d[i++] = d[i++] = d[i++] = v;
    i++;
  }
  bw.ctx.putImageData(imgD, 0, 0);
}

//Using per pixel processing with cutoff width
function twoTonePixelCutoff(bw, cutoff, threshold) {
  if (cutoff === 0) {
    twoTonePixelP(bw, threshold);
    return;
  }
  const eCurve = (v, p) => {
    var vv;
    return (vv = Math.pow(v, 2)) / (vv + Math.pow(1 - v, 2))
  }
  const imgD = bw.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, bw.width, bw.height);
  const d = imgD.data;
  var i = 0;
  var v;
  const mult = 255 / cutoff;
  const offset = -(threshold * mult) + 127;
  while (i < d.length) {
    v = ((d[i++] + d[i++] + d[i]) / 3) * mult + offset;
    v = v < 0 ? 0 : v > 255 ? 255 : eCurve(v / 255) * 255;
    i -= 2;
    d[i++] = d[i++] = d[i++] = v;
    i++;
  }
  bw.ctx.putImageData(imgD, 0, 0);
}


function OtsuMean(image, type) {
  // Otsu's method, from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method#Variant_2
  //
  // The input argument pixelsNumber is the number of pixels in the given image. The 
  // input argument histogram is a 256-element histogram of a grayscale image 
  // different gray-levels.
  // This function outputs the threshold for the image.
  function otsu(histogram, pixelsNumber) {
    var sum = 0, sumB = 0, wB = 0, wF = 0, mB, mF, max = 0, between, threshold = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      wB += histogram[i];
      if (wB === 0) continue;
      wF = pixelsNumber - wB;
      if (wF === 0) break;
      sumB += i * histogram[i];
      mB = sumB / wB;
      mF = (sum - sumB) / wF;
      between = wB * wF * Math.pow(mB - mF, 2);
      if (between > max) {
        max = between;
        threshold = i;
      }
    }
    return threshold>>1;
  }
  const imgD = image.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  const d = imgD.data;
  var histogram = new Uint16Array(256);
  if(type == 2){
    for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
      histogram[Math.round(d[i]*.2126+d[i+1]*.7152+d[i+2]*.0722)]++;
    }
  }else{
    for(var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
      histogram[Math.round(Math.sqrt(d[i]*d[i]*.2126+d[i+1]*d[i+1]*.7152+d[i+2]*d[i+2]*.0722))]++;
    }
  }
  

  return otsu(histogram, image.width * image.height);
}
// finds mean via the perceptual 2,7,1 approx rule rule
function calcMean(image, rule = 0){
  if(rule == 2 || rule == 3){
    return OtsuMean(image, rule);
  }
  const imgD = image.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
  const d = imgD.data;
  var i = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var count = 0

  while (i < d.length) {
    if(rule == 0){
      sum += d[i++] * 0.2 + d[i++] * 0.7 + d[i++] * 0.1;
      count += 1;
    }else{
      sum += d[i++] + d[i++] + d[i++];
      count += 3;
    }
    i++;
  }

  return (sum / count) | 0;

}

// creates a canvas copy of an image.
function makeImageEditable(image) {
  const c = document.createElement("canvas");
  c.width = (image.width / 2) | 0;
  c.height = (image.height / 2) | 0;
  c.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  c.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  return c;
}
function updateEditableImage(image,editable) {
  editable.width = (image.width / (scaleFull ? 1 : 2)) | 0;
  editable.height = (image.height / (scaleFull ? 1 : 2)) | 0;
  editable.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, editable.width, editable.height);
}





// load test image and when loaded start UI
function start() {
  image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  image.src = imageSrcs[0];
  imageStatus.textContent = "Loading image 1";
  image.onload = ()=>{
    imageBWA = makeImageEditable(image);
    imageBWB = makeImageEditable(image);
    imageBWC = makeImageEditable(image);
    canA.appendChild(imageBWA);
    canB.appendChild(imageBWB);
    canC.appendChild(imageBWC);
    imageStatus.textContent = "Loaded image 1.";
    startUI();
  }
}
function selectImage(idx){
  imageStatus.textContent = "Loading image " + idx;
  image.src = imageSrcs[idx];
  image.onload = ()=>{
    updateEditableImage(image, imageBWA);
    updateEditableImage(image, imageBWB);
    updateEditableImage(image, imageBWC);
    thresholdC = thresholdB = thresholdA = -1; // force update
    imageStatus.textContent = "Loaded image " + idx;
  }
}
function toggleScale(){
  scaleFull = !scaleFull;
  imageStatus.textContent = scaleFull ? "Image full scale." : "Image half scale"; 
  updateEditableImage(image, imageBWA);
  updateEditableImage(image, imageBWB);
  updateEditableImage(image, imageBWC);
  thresholdC = thresholdB = thresholdA = -1; // force update
}
function findMean(e){

      imageBWB.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageBWB.width, imageBWB.height);
      var t = inputThresholdB.value = inputThresholdC.value = calcMean(imageBWB,e.target.dataset.method);
      imageStatus.textContent = "New threshold calculated " + t + ". Method : "+ e.target.dataset.name;
      thresholdB = thresholdC = -1;
};
  

// start the UI
function startUI() {
  imageControl.className = "imageSel";
  selImage1Btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>selectImage(0));
  selImage2Btn.addEventListener("click",(e)=>selectImage(1));
  togFullsize.addEventListener("click",toggleScale);
  findMean1.addEventListener("click",findMean);
  findMean2.addEventListener("click",findMean);
  findMean3.addEventListener("click",findMean);

  // updates top image
  function update1() {
    if (amountA !== inputAmountA.value || thresholdA !== inputThresholdA.value) {
      amountA = inputAmountA.value;
      thresholdA = inputThresholdA.value;
      inputAmountValueA.textContent = amountA;
      inputThresholdValueA.textContent = thresholdA;
      imageBWA.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageBWA.width, imageBWA.height);
      twoTone(imageBWA, amountA, thresholdA);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update1);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update1);

  // updates center image
  function update2() {
    if (thresholdB !== inputThresholdB.value) {
      thresholdB = inputThresholdB.value;
      inputThresholdValueB.textContent = thresholdB;
      imageBWB.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageBWB.width, imageBWB.height);
      twoTonePixelP(imageBWB, thresholdB);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update2);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update2);

  // updates bottom image
  function update3() {
    if (cutoffC !== inputCutoffC.value || thresholdC !== inputThresholdC.value) {
      cutoffC = inputCutoffC.value;
      thresholdC = inputThresholdC.value;
      inputCutoffValueC.textContent = cutoffC;
      inputThresholdValueC.textContent = thresholdC;
      imageBWC.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageBWC.width, imageBWC.height);
      twoTonePixelCutoff(imageBWC, cutoffC, thresholdC);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update3);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update3);

}
```

```css
.imageIso {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size : 12px;
}
.imageSel {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#imageStatus {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.btn {
  margin: 2px;
  font-size : 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background : white;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor : pointer;
}
.btn:hover {
  background : #DDD;
}  

body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-siae: 12px;
}

canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageSel hide" id="imageControl">
<input class="btn" id="selImage1Btn" type="button" value="Image 1"></input>
<input class="btn" id="selImage2Btn" type="button" value="Image 2"></input>
<input class="btn" id="togFullsize" type="button" value="Toggle fullsize"></input>
<input class="btn" id="findMean1" type="button" value="Mean M1" data-method=0 data-name="perceptual mean approximation" title="Get the image mean to use as threshold value using perceptual mean approximation"></input>
<input class="btn" id="findMean2" type="button" value="Mean M2" data-method=1 data-name="Pixel RGB sum mean" title="Get threshold value using RGB sum mean"></input>
<input class="btn" id="findMean3" type="button" value="Mean Otsu" data-method=2 data-name="Otsu's method" title="Get threshold value using Otsu's method"></input>
<div id="imageStatus"></div>
</div>



<div class="imageIso">
  Using per pixel processing simple threshold. Quick in terms of pixel processing but produces a hard boundary at the threshold value.<br>
  <div id="canB"></div>
  Threshold<input id="inputThresholdB" type="range" min="1" max="255" step="1" value="128"></input><span id="inputThresholdValueB"></span>
</div>

<div class="imageIso">
  Using per pixel processing with cutoff width. This softens the cutoff boundary by gray scaling the values at the threshold.<br>
  <div id="canC"></div>
  Cutoff width<input id="inputCutoffC" type="range" min="0" max="64" step="0.1" value="8"></input><span id="inputCutoffValueC"></span><br> Threshold
  <input id="inputThresholdC" type="range" min="1" max="255" step="1" value="128"></input><span id="inputThresholdValueC"></span>
</div>

<div class="imageIso">
  <h2>Means not applied to this image</h2>
  Using stacked global composite operations. The quickest method and does not require secure pixel access. Though threshold and cutoff are imprecise.<br>
  <div id="canA"></div>
  Amount<input id="inputAmountA" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="75"></input><span id="inputAmountValueA"></span><br> Threshold
  <input id="inputThresholdA" type="range" min="1" max="255" step="1" value="127"></input><span id="inputThresholdValueA"></span>
</div>
```

---

old answer

### The quickest color to black&white using the 2D API

The quickest method for color to BW is as follows

```
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation";
ctx.fillStyle = "#888";  // no saturation
ctx.fillRect(0,0,image.width,image.height);
```

and provides a good result.

As there is always the debate about which way is the right way the rest of the answer and snippets let you compare the various methods and see which you prefer.

#### BW conversion comparison.

Many people tend to use the perceptual conversion either as a linear RGB->BW or logarithmic RGB->BW and will swear by it. Personal it's over rated and needs a experiance eye to detect.

There is technically no correct method as the correct method of conversion depends on so many factors, Overall image brightness and contrast, viewing environment's ambient lighting, individual preferences, media type (display, print, other), any existing image processing, origin image source (jpg,png,etc), camera settings, author's intent, viewing context (is it full screen, a thumb, on a bright blue border, etc)

The demo shows some methods of conversion including the common perceptual linear and log, some methods use direct pixel processing via "ctx.getImageData" and others use the GPU via 2D API to do the processing (up 100 times quicker)

Start the snippet the image will load and then be processed. Once all versions are complete they will be display alongside the original. Click on the image to see what function was used and the time it took to process the image.

Image source: served by Wiki. Attribution : public domain.

```js
const methods = {quickBW, quickPerceptualBW, PerceptualLinear, PerceptualLog, directLum, directLumLog}
const image = new Image;

status("Loading test image.");
setTimeout(start,0);

function status(text){
   const d = document.createElement("div");
   d.textContent = text;
   info.appendChild(d);
}

function makeImageEditable(image){
 const c = document.createElement("canvas");
 c.width = image.width;
 c.height = image.height;
 c.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 c.ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
 return c;
}
function makeImageSideBySide(image,image1){
 const c = document.createElement("canvas");
 c.width = image.width + image1.width;
 c.height = image.height;
 c.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 c.ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
 c.ctx.drawImage(image1,image.width,0);
 return c;
}
function text(ctx, text, y = ctx.canvas.height / 2){
 ctx.font= "32px arial";
 ctx.textAlign = "center";
 ctx.fillStyle = "black";
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
 ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
 ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
 ctx.fillText(text,ctx.canvas.width / 2, y+2);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillText(text,ctx.canvas.width / 2, y);
}
 
function quickBW(bw){ 

 bw.ctx.save(); 
 bw.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation";
 bw.ctx.fillStyle = "#888";  // no saturation
 bw.ctx.fillRect(0,0,bw.width,bw.height);
 bw.ctx.restore();
 return bw;
}
function quickPerceptualBW(bw){ 
 bw.ctx.save(); 
 bw.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
 var col = "rgb(";
 col += ((255 * 0.2126 * 1.392) | 0) + ",";
 col += ((255 * 0.7152 * 1.392) | 0) + ",";
 col += ((255 * 0.0722 * 1.392) | 0) + ")";
  bw.ctx.fillStyle = col;
 bw.ctx.fillRect(0,0,bw.width,bw.height);
 bw.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "saturation";
 bw.ctx.fillStyle = "#888";  // no saturation
 bw.ctx.fillRect(0,0,bw.width,bw.height);
 bw.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";
  bw.ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
  bw.ctx.drawImage(bw,0,0);
 bw.ctx.restore();
 return bw;
}
function PerceptualLinear(bw){ 
 const imgD = bw.ctx.getImageData(0,0,bw.width, bw.height);
 const d = imgD.data;
 var i = 0;
 var v;
 while(i < d.length){
  v = d[i++] * 0.2126 + d[i++] * 0.7152 + d[i] * 0.0722;
  i -= 2;
  d[i++] = d[i++] = d[i++] = v;
  i++;
 }
 bw.ctx.putImageData(imgD,0,0);
 return bw;
}
function PerceptualLog(bw){ 
 const imgD = bw.ctx.getImageData(0,0,bw.width, bw.height);
 const d = imgD.data;
 var i = 0;
 var v;
 while(i < d.length){
  v = Math.sqrt(d[i] * d[i++] * 0.2126 + d[i] * d[i++] * 0.7152 + d[i] *d[i] * 0.0722);
  i -= 2;
  d[i++] = d[i++] = d[i++] = v;
  i++;
 }
 bw.ctx.putImageData(imgD,0,0);
 return bw;
}

function directLum(bw){ 
 const imgD = bw.ctx.getImageData(0,0,bw.width, bw.height);
 const d = imgD.data;
 var i = 0;
 var r,g,b,v;
 while(i < d.length){
  r = d[i++];
  g = d[i++];
  b = d[i];
  v = (Math.min(r, g, b) + Math.max(r, g, b)) / 2.2;
        i -= 2;
  d[i++] = d[i++] = d[i++] = v;
  i++;
 }
 bw.ctx.putImageData(imgD,0,0);
 return bw;
}
function directLumLog(bw){ 
 const imgD = bw.ctx.getImageData(0,0,bw.width, bw.height);
 const d = imgD.data;
 var i = 0;
 var r,g,b,v;
 while(i < d.length){
  r = d[i] * d[i++];
  g = d[i] * d[i++];
  b = d[i] * d[i];
  v = Math.pow((Math.min(r, g, b) + Math.max(r, g, b)/2) ,1/2.05);
    i -= 2;
  d[i++] = d[i++] = d[i++] = v;
  i++;
 }
 bw.ctx.putImageData(imgD,0,0);
 return bw;
}


function start(){
  image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"
 image.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png";
  
  status("Image loaded, pre processing.");
 image.onload = ()=>setTimeout(process,0);
} 
function addImageToDOM(element,data){
  element.style.width = "512px"
  element.style.height = "256px"
 element.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  text(element.ctx,"Method : " + data.name + " Time : " + data.time.toFixed(3) + "ms",36);
 });
 document.body.appendChild(element);
}
function process(){
  const pKeys = Object.keys(methods);
 const images = pKeys.map(()=>makeImageEditable(image));
 const results = {};
  status("Convert to BW");
  setTimeout(()=>{
      pKeys.forEach((key,i)=>{
        const now = performance.now();
        methods[key](images[i]);
        results[key] = {};
        results[key].time = performance.now() - now;
        results[key].name = key;
      });
      pKeys.forEach((key,i)=>{
        addImageToDOM(makeImageSideBySide(images[i],image),results[key]);
      })
      status("Complete!");
      status("Click on image that you think best matches");
      status("The original luminance to see which method best suits your perception.");
      status("The function used and the time to process in ms 1/1000th sec");
  },1000);

}
```

```css
canvas {border : 2px solid black;}
body {font-family : arial; font-size : 12px; }
```

```html
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: This is good information. I think OP was looking for a thresholding effect rather than gray scale though. I believe his intention was to find the quickest method to make the image binary where pixels are either completely black or completely white.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Lol yes you are correct. I should have read the question rather than question title and the answer. Oh well no harm done.

Comment: @Blindman67 Hi. so In this sense, there is no recomendation to weigth the colors (ej: 0.7152 R .. and so on) for a thresholding?. By the way this was great

Comment: @OscarMuñoz For thresholding there is no standard.